# How to display date seven days before the supposed date "tarikh_mulali" using mySQL?

Tags: mysql

**MySQL below is given. How to set condition to display date seven days before the supposed date "tarikh_mulali"**

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM ((maklumat_pemohon INNER JOIN maklumat_tawaran ON 
 maklumat_pemohon.noic_pemohon = maklumat_tawaran.noic_pemohon) INNER JOIN 
 maklumat_status ON maklumat_pemohon.noic_pemohon = maklumat_status.noic_pemohon) WHERE 
 (tarikh_mulali >= DAY(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 7 DAY)))  AND status_lapordiri = 
 'MELAPOR DIRI'";
```

this is the output.

[image]

I want to make it not display if the date is not in the range 7 days before the actual date (10/06/2022). So, I want to display the date from 04/06/2022, 05/06/2022, 06/06/2022, 07/06/2022. 08/06/2022, 09/06/2022 and 10/06/2022. After 10/06/2022 it will not display the output.

Comment: It will be helpful if you add some example data and your desired output.

Comment: I have already put the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If I not misunderstand, you asking the way to display earlier 7 days before tarikh_mulali?

SELECT tarikh_mulali - INTERVAL 7 DAY from ......

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUBDATE()
`SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE,7)` will display 7 days before current date.
For future date, use `SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE,-7)`

Comment: i need to put it in WHERE clause or SELECT clause?

Comment: Anywhere as per your requirement.